# title, content copied and title, name used! trademark issue?

Tags: content, copyright, legal, protection

I have a video website, server and domain bought 3 months 1 week ago, website actually started 1 month 1 week ago. Domain name plain and simple, easy to remember, bought with a yearly fee, nothing similar exists. Domain name appears in all pages' title.

Around a week ago, started coming up with odd websites in google searches: my website has 0 pagerank (not enough traffic, no advertising yet and no backlinks, a maximum of 10,000 pageloads a day, this week's average 3000 pageviews a day - because of the time of year? ) other websites with higher pagerank (heck, it's not that hard to beat a 0 pagerank-1 month old website) have started using my name in their content titles! like name, sometimes including .com!

I wish not to reveal my website address for ethical purposes, so for now i shall call it foofoo.com

So my pages are: foofoo.com - best free video sharing site: free full hd episodes, free flash games etc... Lame Video title man runs on the street with no shoes video - foofoo.com Count Sheeps till you go to sleep flash game - foofoo.com

google searches for foofoo.com point directly to my website BUT google searches for foofoo point to some pages like: notfoo.com/foofoo-com-stolen-title-and-vid-for-views with title like foofoo.com vid title here bla bla

searching google for "foofoo" 2 weeks ago would place me 10th, and going up. searching for it now places me somewhere on 30th-35th and going down! all places before me are taken by titles containing my name, domain, title, content title etc and I don't know what to do about it! All my pages have a copyright notice at the bottom of the page and i have a terms and conditions on my website.

I did not register a trademark, but searched for it and no one has registered a trademark containing my domain name. I do not know what to do... can someone please advise? I am currently reading about legal stuff, trademark and such, but just started today so it will be tough. Also, I cannot afford any payed advise, such as a lawyer... that's mainly the reason for which I haven't yet payed for a registered trademark.Does anyone have an idea on what could be the cost of registering a trademark?

Please help me solve this issue... Thanks in advance to all of you going to answer and help me!

Answer (score 1):

Filing a [DMCA (Digital Millenium Copyright Act) notice](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-dmca/19256/) or a spam report is [one way](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LsB19wTt0Q) to let Google know that your content is original & make them take action against the site that has copied your content.

Answer (score 0):

Over a period of time Google algorithm will learn that you are the real foofoo.com and not the other sites.

This will happen once you have more genuine users and followers who will spread back-links for you.

Registering a trademark will not help you a lot in the SERP fight , but it is a definitely a good idea for a long run. (sorry but i don't know much about trademarks)

Comment: it's ok, thank you very much! I will try to optimize my site as far as I can. I will also fight for some backlinks. I have read some about trademarks and it's actually not a big deal, just they are important to have (if you don't want to pay 400$, it's very good for beginning to put a small (tm) mark next to what you consider yours, this is for other people reading this post.) Thank you very much for your answer, I did not know about google's algorithm. Now I feel a little bit better about my situation.  Thanks again!

Comment: I forgot to mention about the sandbox; In initial phase of a site it has to go through a  Sandbox phase (http://www.webduckdesigns.com/pages/website-resources/sandbox.php) it can last upto 3 months.

Comment: damn... i recognize my site all over the description of factors that take a website to the sandbox...damn... :(